# makefile with debug option

Tags: variables, makefile

I am kinda rookie in makefile field but trying to write makefile that would go in two modes: normal mode `make` outputing executable file called say `bingo` depending on some files and a mode `make debug` outputing   executable file called `bingo.debug` that shall be compiled with debug option. I'm trying to use target variable with the following result:

```
PROGRAM = bingo
SUFIX = .debug
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
DEBUG = -g -D DEBUG

all: $(PROGRAM)
debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUG)
debug: PROGRAM += $(SUFIX)
debug: all

file1.o: file1.c file1.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

file2.o: file2.c file2.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<


$(PROGRAM).o: $(PROGRAM).c 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(PROGRAM): file1.o file2.o ($PROGRAM).o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM) *.o
```

It looks like `make debug` correctly compiles the file with debug flags but it does not change the file name (i.e. both modes outputs the same `bingo` file). Any help much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use target-specific variables in targets.  [The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) is very clear that they are available only in recipes.

In general it's problematic to do things this way, because make has no idea which objects were built with debug and which weren't.  If you forget to do a complete clean and/or run `make` the wrong way then you'll get a mix of different object files: some compiled with debug and some not.

Instead, you should put your debug object files in a different directory from your non-debug object files so you don't have to worry about that.